# How to simplify this? What did I do wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(3-\sqrt3) (2-\sqrt3)-\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{27}.$$
So I simplified the $\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt{27}$ part into

$$\sqrt 3\cdot\sqrt{9\cdot3} = \sqrt3\cdot3\cdot\sqrt3=4\cdot\sqrt3$$

Then I multiplied the brackets :

$$6+\sqrt3-2\cdot\sqrt3-3\cdot\sqrt3 =6-4\cdot\sqrt3.$$
Then minus the $4\cdot\sqrt3$ we got

$$6-8\cdot\sqrt3$$

However the answer should be $-5\cdot\sqrt3$
How can I get that answer, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was in the equality $$\sqrt 3 \cdot 3 \cdot \sqrt 3 = 4\cdot \sqrt3$$ which is false.

$$\sqrt{3}\sqrt{9\cdot 3} = \sqrt{3}\cdot 3\cdot \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot 3 = 3\cdot 3 = 9 \neq 4\cdot \sqrt 3$$

Also, you made a mistake in multiplying the brackets:

$$(3-\sqrt 3)(2-\sqrt 3) = 6-3\sqrt 3 -2\sqrt 3 + 3$$
which is not what you got.

Comment: Oh wow... I did the same mistake before too, i need to pay attention to this more, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JohnFire You did **two** very basic mistakes here. You need to be **much** more careful. Don't rush it. Take your time, and rather than hurrying to the solution, write a couple of extra lines, just so you don't make too many steps at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Second line, second equal sign is wrong.

$\sqrt{3}\cdot 3 \cdot \sqrt{3} = 9$

Multiplying the brackets yelds:

$6 - 2\sqrt{3} - 3\sqrt{3} +3 = 9 - 5\sqrt{3}$

Putting it all together:

$9 - 5\sqrt{3} - 9 = -5\cdot \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Thank you, I need to pay attention more, already made the same mistake once...